# testng calling parameterized method in another method

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, testng, parameterized

I'm new to TestNG and Selenium. I'm having this problem and untill now nothing helped.
I want to create a method to run multiple browsers simultaneously and call that method where ever I need. below is my code.. problem is when I am calling it from another class/method it runs just one browser which is passed as parameter. kindly guide me where am I wrong

```
    public class CommonMethods {
    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    @Parameters("browser")
    public void beforeTest(String browser)throws Exception{

        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {

            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            System.out.println("1");
    }

        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("IE")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "resource\\IEDriverServer.exe");
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            System.out.println("2");
        }

        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","resource\\chromedriver.exe");
            // To remove message "You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --ignore-certificate-errors.
            // Stability and security will suffer."
            // Add an argument 'test-type'
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("test-type");
            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            System.out.println("3");
    }
    }


}
```

This is the testng.xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
 <suite name="Suite" parallel="tests">
 <test name="FirefoxTest">
 <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>
 <classes>
     <class name="mycompqa.helper.Calling"/>
  <class name="mycompqa.helper.CommonMethods"/>
 </classes>
 </test> <!-- Test -->

<test name="ChromeTest">
<parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
<classes>
    <class name="mycompqa.helper.Calling"/>
  <class name="mycompqa.helper.CommonMethods"/>      
 </classes>
 </test>

<test name="IETest">
<parameter name="browser" value="IE"/>
<classes>
    <class name="mycompqa.helper.Calling"/>
  <class name="mycompqa.helper.CommonMethods"/>
</classes>
</test>

 </suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

This is how I'm calling it

```
    package mycompqa.helper;

     import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
      import org.testng.annotations.Test;

       public class Calling {

         CommonMethods com=new CommonMethods();

    @Test
    public void run() throws Exception{
        com.beforeTest("firefox");
        WebDriver driver=com.driver;
        driver.get("http://www.snapdeal.com");

}
}
```

Now this code runs just in the Firefox browser but what I want is that all browsers should run simultaneously. Offcourse  when I'm passing firefox as a parameter then only that browser will run. What should I do for simultaneous execution of all the browsers?

Could you provide some links where I could learn a bit more on these topics (
apart from selenium.org and testng.org) ?

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you should use the testng xml to run the tests. But in case you want this setup you can create threads of the class CommonMethods and then you can create multiple instances of that and call with different browsers as parameter.

But I would have done it in this way

```
class a {

Private String Browser;
WebDriver c;
@test
@Parameters("browser")
public void driver(String Browser)
//create instance of Webdriver


  //use the driver

}
}
```

And have a testng xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
 <suite name="Suite" parallel="tests">
 <test name="FirefoxTest">
 <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>
 <classes>
     <class name="a"/>
 </classes>
 </test> <!-- Test -->
<test name="ChromeTest">
 <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome"/>
 <classes>
     <class name="a"/>
 </classes>
 </test> <!-- Test -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium grid for running your script simultaneously on all browsers. For this you just need to add `Selenium Standalone Server`jar in your editor. You may download the jar from below mentioned link:
http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Have a look to this video to understand how grid works.
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAvzKA9wsbo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAvzKA9wsbo)

Let me know if you are still facing problem.